# .xlsx to csv including changing number format and validating data

Tags: python-2.7, loops, csv, utf-8, number-formatting

I am stuck with a small project to validate data of a .xlsx file. Each column has different kind of data in them, from numbers, to text only, dates, etc.

What I want accomplish is to open a .xlsx file, change the number format (e.g.: numbers from 100.0 to 100 by applying the Excel-numformats ('@' for string, 'dd.mm.yyyy' for date, '0' for integer numbers, '0.00' for decimals, etc.)). In the next step I'm validating the data of each column by iterating through each cell amd character (I'm replacing the characters with dictionaries) and then save it as a csv with Utf-8 encoding.

Currently I'm using xlrd module for opening the .xlsx files with utf-8 encoding (encoding_overwrite) and then changing the number formats with xlsxwriter. The problem is that I would have to save the changed data as a .xlsx file, then reopen it with xlrd again, valdidate the characters and then save it as .csv with unicode csv module. But I would like to skip the step of saving the file once again and then reopen it.
I have already tried openpyxl too, but it takes way too long to open "big" files and to manipulate the data.

Is there any way to return the data of xlsxwriter's workbook class to xlrd or does xlsxwriter have a method of iterating through its data and changing its values (I couldn't find anything in the documentation of both libraries)? Or maybe there's a more powerful library for my situation.

Please enlighten me.

Code examples:

```
    # Opening .xlsx-File (xlrd)
    input_file = open_workbook(curr_path + "/" + filename + '.xlsx', encoding_override="cp1252")</code><br>
    # Creating the dictionaries for replace
    def create_dicts(file_flag):
        global dict_letters
        global dict_numbers
        global dict_special
        global dict_control
        global dict_greek
        if file_flag <> 'sonstige':
            dict_letters = create_dict("Buchstaben")
            dict_numbers = create_dict("Zahlen")
            dict_special = create_dict("Sonderzeichen")
            dict_control = create_dict("Kontrollzeichen")
            dict_greek = create_dict("Griechisch")
        else:
            dict_all = create_dict("All")
        print "Dicts created"
    def create_dict(ws):
        keys =[]
        values =[]
        cell = ''
        dict_xl_ws = ''
        # Either create a dictionary containing all sheets or one for each sheet (depending on the parameter ws)
        if ws == "All":
            for curr_sheet in range(dict_xl_wb.nsheets):
                dict_xl_ws = dict_xl_wb.sheet_by_index(curr_sheet)
                for curr_row in range(dict_xl_ws.nrows):
                    for curr_col in [0,1]:
                        if str(dict_xl_ws.cell_value(curr_row, curr_col)) not in skip_list:
                            if curr_col == 0:
                                keys.append(str(dict_xl_ws.cell_value(curr_row, curr_col)).upper())
                            elif curr_col == 1:
                                values.append(str(dict_xl_ws.cell_value(curr_row, curr_col)).upper())
        else:
            dict_xl_ws = dict_xl_wb.sheet_by_name(ws)
            for curr_row in range(dict_xl_ws.nrows):
                for curr_col in [0,1]:
                    if str(dict_xl_ws.cell_value(curr_row, curr_col)) not in skip_list:
                        if curr_col == 0:
                            keys.append(str(dict_xl_ws.cell_value(curr_row, curr_col)).upper())
                        elif curr_col == 1:
                            values.append(str(dict_xl_ws.cell_value(curr_row, curr_col)).upper())
        return dict(zip(keys,values))
    # Calling the create_dicts() function
    create_dicts(file_flag)
    # Creating Workbook and Worksheet from class (xlsxwriter)
    test = xlsxwriter.Workbook("test.xlsx")
    test_ws = test.add_worksheet("TEST")

    # Defining the number formats
    text_format = test.add_format({'num_format': '@'})
    integer_format = test.add_format({'num_format': '0'})
    double_format = test.add_format({'num_format': '0.00'})
    date_format = test.add_format({'num_format': 'DD.MM.YYYY'})

    # Creating dictionary (key = start column; value = end column)
    integer_dict = {0:1,4:5,8:9,16:16,19:19,25:26,28:29,33:33,35:35,42:42,44:46,48:49}
    for key,value in integer_dict.iteritems():
        # Applying the formats for each column in test_ws
        test_ws.set_column(key, value,20, integer_format)

    # After that I'd like to iterate through the data of xlsxwriter's workbook/worksheet class and change the data by replacing characters with those in the dictionaries. That part is already coded, but I need a proper library to work with

    # Creating a csv-file to write the validated data into
    output_file = codecs.open(curr_path + "/" + filename + '_OUT.csv','wb', encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: I suggest you skip xlsxwriter entirely. Create the output csv from the data you get from xlrd directly. Do the reformatting of numbers and dates with Python's string formatting methods and `datetime.strftime()` etc.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. 
is there no library that can change number format like excel and has the option to iterate through its data?
the thing is that if for example a date is formated as a number in excel, then it could look like this "42857". I don't think that the strftime() function can format it back to "02.05.2017".

Comment: If I recall correctly, you can tell `xlrd` that a cell's content is a date, and it will return a `datetime.date[time]` object instead of the underlying number. Then you can use that object's `strftime` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @lenz was pointing out correctly, XLRD has a method to change a cell's value to an excel-date.
So I used the xlrd.xldate.xldate_as_datetime() function to change the value. The solution was the following:

```
date_variable = xlrd.xldate.xldate_as_datetime(ws.cell_value(cell_row, cell_col), 0).strftime('%d.%m.%Y')
```

And in order to correctly change a float number to integer I used the following code snippet:

```
integer_variable = '{0:g}'.format(Decimal(ws.cell_value(cell_row, cell_col)))
```

I hope those two lines will help as much as they did help me!